# How can I import tasks from Wunderlist to GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, wunderlist

I need to transfer tasks from Wunderlist to GitLab - what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try **wunderlist-to-gitlab** at https://gitlab.com/moveto-io/wunderlist-to-gitlab

It involves exporting your Wunderlist tasks to JSON, converting them to .csv, then importing the .csv file to GitLab.

Disclaimer: I cobbled this together from https://github.com/tiangolo/wunderlist2csv and https://github.com/grib0/gitlab-import-issues